# Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client at new NodeError

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

iam tryna make a lil reload animation as middleware between the req and res so when the user waits for a response, a reload waiting runs in browser (im using nodejs & express, and ejs templating engine)

this is the app.js code

```js
const ejs = require('ejs');
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.render('base', { child: 'middleware' });
    next();
});
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('base', { child: 'child' });
});
app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Server is running on port 3000');
});
```

this is base.ejs

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parent Template</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <!-- Common header content -->
    </header>
    <main>
      <!-- Content specific to child files will go here -->
      <%-include (child);-%>
    </main>
    <footer>
      <!-- Common footer content -->
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

the two child files to extend from base.ejs

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/middleware.css" />
<section>
  <div class="site_title"></div>
</section>
```

and

```
<section>
  <h1>Welcome to the Child Page!</h1>
  <!-- Additional content specific to the child file -->
</section>
```

I wrote this code as clear above
base.ejs, the parent to include home.ejs and middleware_animation.ejs
its kinda messy for the nodejs templatning engine, would you please recommend other easier engines to start with?

Comment: pug template engine: https://pugjs.org/api/express.html

Answer (score 1):

Delete this rule or specify a route:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.render('base', { child: 'middleware' });
    next();
});
```

I think the error message comes from this rule. With `res` a response already goes out. So `next` is too much here. In general, this route makes no sense, since no path is specified and all requests go in here.

Comment: yes but the logiv of rendering a eload animation while the user is waiting in a different routing url firest then redirect him to his typed url is not good?

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do. But I am sure that every request gets stuck in the first app.use().